# flutter)When the dynamic link page is accessed through a redirect, it does not work as expected

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I applied dynamic linking to my current project.
When the user presses the 'share' button, a preview page appears. And when the user presses the 'Run' button on the preview page, the dynamic link should be executed.

Share button → Preview page(web view) → Run button press → Run My Application → Go to the desired screen.

in this case, the app only runs and does not move to the desired screen.
However, if the preview page is omitted, that is, if the 'share' button is clicked and the link is linked directly to a dynamic link, it works well.

The redirect address connected when the ‘share’ button is pressed is the dynamic link address. I confirmed the same.

Below is the dynamic link reception code.

```dart
Future<void> listenDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks firebaseLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data = await firebaseLink.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? initialLink = data?.link;

    if (initialLink != null) {
      moveByDynamicLink(initialLink);
    }
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    firebaseLink.onLink.listen((PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        dynamicLinks.add(dynamicLink);
        final Uri curLink = dynamicLinks.last.link;
        moveByDynamicLink(curLink);

    });
  }

void moveByDynamicLink(Uri deepLink) async {
    try {
      if (deepLink.authority == "SECRET") {
        if (deepLink.path == "/qwefqwerqwerqer") {
          int? campaignIndex = int.tryParse(
              (deepLink.queryParameters["campaign_index"].toString()));

          if (campaignIndex != null) {
              context.vxNav.push(Uri.parse(NewCampaignDetailScreen.routeName),
                  params: {
                    "campaign_index": campaignIndex,
                    "hero_key": campaignIndex
                  });
        } else if (deepLink.path == "/main") {
          int? screenId =
              int.tryParse((deepLink.queryParameters["screen_id"].toString()));

            context.vxNav.push(Uri.parse(HomeAdaptor.routeName),
                params: {"screen_id": (screenId ?? 0).toString()});
            return;
          
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //error handle
    }
  }
```